# Serialize field object of an Java object using Gson

Tags: java, gson

I am writing a function which serialize a Java object into Json using Gson.

The problem I have is that it only serialize primitive fields of my class but not object fields. For example. I have two classes like:

```
class TestClass {
    public int i = 10;
    public TestClass2 tc2;
}

class TestClass2 {
    public int j = 20;
}
```

And my test is:

```
@Test
public void shouldSerializeSimpleObjectIntoJson() {
    TestClass tc = new TestClass();

    String json = new Gson().toJson(tc);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

The Json output is:

```
{"i":10}
```

It does not contain the fields of tc2.

How can I config Gson to recursively encode an object into Json?

Thanks

Comment: Have `tc2` be something other than `null`. There's nothing to encode in your example.

Answer (score 3):

The field is ignored because it's `null`. From the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support):

> **The default behaviour that is implemented in Gson is that null object fields are ignored.**  This allows for a more compact output format; however, the client must define a default value for these fields as the JSON format is converted back into its Java.
>
> Here's how you would configure a Gson instance to output null:
>
> ```
> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
> ```

If you set `tc.tc2` to a value other than `null`, you should see its fields in the output file.

Answer (score 2):

With your specific example, add a constructor which will make a new instance of tc2:

```
public TestClass()
{
   tc2 = new TestClass2();
}
```

and see if it helps. If in your real code the class which is similar to TestClass2 has reference classes as well, create a new instance of them as well

Answer (score 2):

In Java, object fields are not initialized by default, that means the tc2 field will be null unless you set it to something. Gson ignores null fields by default, and thus it's not serializing it.

You could initialize the field in the constructor, like the other answer correctly says. Or you could also initialize it doing the following:

```
class TestClass {
    public int i = 10;
    public TestClass2 tc2 = new TestClass2();
}
```